# Select articles which are in a table but not in a second table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application which uses SQLite 3.

I have these three tables:

```
| Articles    |
+-------------+
| articleId   |
+-------------+
| description |
+-------------+


| OrdeArticle |
+-------------+
| orderId     |
+-------------+
| articleId   |
+-------------+


| EReportArticle |
+----------------+
| eReportId      |
+----------------+
| articleId      |
+----------------+
```

I want to select all articles which are on `OrdeArticle` table but they aren't on `EReportArticle` table.

Here is my **not working** SQL sentence:

```
SELECT 
   Article.articleId,
   Article.description
FROM
   Article,
   OrdeArticle,
   EReportArticle
WHERE
   OrdeArticle.orderId = ? AND 
   Article.articleId = OrdeArticle.articleId AND
   EReportArticle.eReportId = ? AND
   Article.articleId != EReportArticle.articleId;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using IN statement to check if articleId exists in one table and doesn't in another

```
SELECT articleId, description
FROM Articles
WHERE articleId IN (SELECT articleId FROM OrdeArticle) AND
articleId NOT IN (SELECT articleId FROM EReportArticle)
```